# Can I mute the other party's voice with livekit?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, next.js, webrtc

I develop meeting applications with React and livekit.

I want to mute the voices of other users in the room, is there a good way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

From the client side, first you need to acquire a list of the current RemoteTrackPublications, either through caching the objects returned on [subscriptions](https://docs.livekit.io/client/receive/#track-subscription) or by querying a room's participants directly:

```js
let remoteTrackPublications = room.participants.flatMap(participant => participant.audioTracks);
```

Once the list has been acquired, call setEnabled:

```js
let deafen = true;
remoteTrackPublications.forEach(publication => publication.set_enabled(!deafen))
```